# Java метод Character.toChars работа с юникод

Tags: java, unicode, char

прошу не минусовать начинающего Trainee. Делаю метод, который будет возвращать строку из трех смайликов. Смайлы в интовом массиве размером в 11 ячеек. Нужно что бы каждый раз, при вызове этого метода возвращалась строка с тремя рандомными смайликами. Пока мои размышления привели меня к коду ниже. Прошу уважаемых людей помочь с код ревью. Ибо даже мне, как начинающему, код очень не нравится (((

```
public static String getEmo (){
        int[] smile = {0x1F525, 0x1F44D, 0x2764, 0x2615, 0x1F917, 0x1F44C, 0x1F607, 0x1F499, 0x1F49A, 0x1F4AF, 0x270C};
        String one = new String(Character.toChars(smile[(int) (Math.random()*11)]));
        String two = new String(Character.toChars(smile[(int) (Math.random()*11)]));
        String three = new String(Character.toChars(smile[(int) (Math.random()*11)]));

        return new String(one + two + three);
    }
```

Comment: Может быть их и не обязательно хранить в массиве. Подскажите, как правильно реализовать это мероприятие.

Comment: В том виде, что написано, может возвращать одинаковые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном коде жёстко закодирована константа 11, не связанная с длиной массива `smile`, повторяются строки для получения одного из трех смайликов, и кроме того вызывается ненужный конструктор `new String(one + two + three)`.

Лучше было бы создать отдельные небольшие методы для генерации одного смайлика и соответственно для получения строки необходимой длины, также следует использовать `StringBuilder` для получения строки:

```java
public static String getEmo() {
    return getEmo(3);
}

static String getEmo(int count) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (count-- > 0) {
        sb.append(getRandomEmo());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

static final int[] smile = {
    0x1F525, 0x1F44D, 0x2764, 0x2615, 0x1F917, 0x1F44C, 
    0x1F607, 0x1F499, 0x1F49A, 0x1F4AF, 0x270C
};

static char[] getRandomEmo() {
    return Character.toChars(smile[(int) (Math.random() * smile.length)]);
}
```

---

Альтернативный вариант: воспользоваться методом [`Random::ints(long size, int from, int to)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-), который позволяет сгенерировать поток случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне определенного размера.  Для добавления смайликов/эмотиконов можно воспользоваться методом `StringBuilder::appendCodePoint` без излишнего преобразования посредством `Character::toChars`:

```java
public static String getEmojis() {
    return getEmojis(3);
}

public static String getEmojis(int num) {
    return new Random().ints(num, 0, smile.length)
        .map(i -> smile[i])
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: дай Вам Бог здоровья. Супер! Не сразу понял красоту решения с разбитием на несколько методов, но потом, когда дошло ... БОЛЬШОЕ спасибо !!!